# The IRB.30 Interface cannot be pinged and i cannot SSH into the given IP

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, cloud

**All configuration is done via Juniper Mist.**
In my Juniper EX4300-MP48 I created an interface IRB.30 with address `192.168.31.200`

```
irb {
    unit 30 {
        description it;
        family inet {
            address 192.169.31.200/24;
        }
    }
}
```

and I added VLAN 30:

```
it {
    vlan-id 30;
    l3-interface irb.30;
}
```

but I cannot ping this address, not even from the switch itself.
I ping with `ping 192.168.31.200` and get this result:

```
PING 192.168.31.200 (192.168.31.200): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 192.168.31.200 ping statistics ---
70 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

So it seems that the VLAN is not working correctly or that the interface is down, so I use `show vlans` and get:

```
default-switch          it                    30
                                                           ge-0/0/0.0*
                                                           ge-0/0/10.0
                                                           ge-0/0/11.0
                                                           ge-0/0/12.0
                                                           ge-0/0/13.0
                                                           ge-0/0/14.0
                                                           ge-0/0/15.0
                                                           ge-0/0/4.0
                                                           ge-0/0/5.0
                                                           ge-0/0/6.0
                                                           ge-0/0/7.0
                                                           ge-0/0/8.0
                                                           ge-0/0/9.0
```

Here you can also see that the `interface ge-0/0/0*` has the `*` because that interface is part of a trunk. This is the **Uplink interface**
So I run the command `show interfaces irb.30 terse` and get:

```
Interface               Admin Link Proto    Local                 Remote
irb.30                  up    up   inet     192.169.31.200/24
```

which clearly states that the interface is up, so I conclude that the issue is with the actual physical interface and therefore run the command `show interfaces ge-0/0/0 terse` which gives me the same result:

```
Interface               Admin Link Proto    Local                 Remote
ge-0/0/0                up    up
ge-0/0/0.0              up    up   eth-switch
```

So guys and gals... Please help an actual IT idiot :) I don't know where to go next or if I missed something in the initial setup.

---

**EDIT 1**

It was suggested i ping the arp cache, so I ran the command `show arp` which gives me

```
MAC Address       Address         Name                      Interface               Flags
94:ff:3c:6a:6d:93 192.168.31.1    192.168.31.1              vme.0                   none
04:5c:6c:44:87:31 192.168.31.13   192.168.31.13             vme.0                   none
b8:c2:53:e7:3c:2d 192.168.31.14   192.168.31.14             vme.0                   none
98:f2:b3:45:d1:00 192.168.31.20   192.168.31.20             vme.0                   none
00:15:65:c5:7b:93 192.168.31.106  192.168.31.106            vme.0                   none
10:c3:7b:6e:97:bc 192.168.31.122  192.168.31.122            vme.0                   none
Total entries: 6
```

I pinged all the various addresses and surely they responded, but I think it might be an issue that the .200 address is not present. But I'll have to figure that out somehow.

Comment: Have you checked the pinging machine's ARP cache, whether the MAC got resolved?

Answer (score 5):

You have put the wrong ip address in the config. You have put an 9 instead of an 8.

```
address 192.169.31.200/24;
```

Should be

```
address 192.168.31.200/24;
```

Comment: It's always the little things.